# Pr. 5 of chapter 1 of Walter Rudin.

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving, upper-lower-bounds

> **Pr 5.** Let $A$ be a nonempty set of real no. Which is bdd below. Let $-A$ be set of all no. $-x; x \in A$. Prove $\inf(A)=-\sup(-A)$.

**My attempt:**
If $x>0, \inf(A) \ge 0$ & by def $\inf(A) \le x$, for all $x\in A$.
Then, $-x < 0$, any $\mathbb R^+$ real no. is an upper bdd of set $-A$. Thus it has a LUB. $\sup(-A) \le 0$ & by def $\sup(-A) \ge -x$, for all $x\in A$. So, $x \ge -\sup(-A)$. Combining above inequality to obtain $-\sup(-A) \le (x\in A) \ge \inf(A)$. Similar argument can be done for $x \le 0$. The equality holds when $x=-\sup(-A)=\inf(A)$.

**My question is:** What if $\inf(A)$ is not an element of set $A$? Then equality doesn't hold, right? So, $\inf(A) \neq-\sup(-A)$.
This is my first and only solution came to my mind while solving this problem.

There are plenty of correct sol. on internet. Like sol. to selected exercise by sam blinstein(unfortunately now I can't find link to pdf). In that solution it is shown that, it is not possible $\gamma(r) > -\sup(-A) r\ge x, x\in A$. By step-by-step logical argument.
Do I have to do the same thing? If yes, then my sol. is not efficient. I just want to know, why my solution isn't working despite using definition of supremum and infimum.

Comment: Please use MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  It's not very hard to learn. Often just surrounding math by dollar signs makes it look better. Type `$x \in A$` to render $x \in A$.

Comment: Okay. I will learn mathjax. I'm using stack exchange on my phone.

Comment: I don't know how often you plan on using your phone to post, but I have my settings with text replacement on my keyboard. When I type "rrn", my phone types `\mathbb{R}^{n}`, and when I type "bmat", my phone types `\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}`, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are breaking up the cases: $x<0$, $x>0$, and $x=0$. I think you should just show that $\forall x \in -A \,, x \le -\operatorname{inf}(A)$, and that if $y < -\operatorname{inf}(A)$, then $\exists x \in -A$ such that $y<x$. Then you will have shown that $\operatorname{sup}(-A)=-\operatorname{inf}(A)$

Comment: If you are allowed to use that a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is bounded below has a greatest lower bound, then we know that $A$ has an infimum. So I would first show that $\forall x \in -A \, , x \le -\operatorname{inf}(A)$. You don't want to *assume* that $\operatorname{sup}(-A) = -\operatorname{inf}(A)$, since that is what you want to show, ***but*** since that is what you want to show, then you show that by first showing that $-\operatorname{inf}(A)$ is an upper bound for $-A$. Then you show that it is the least upper bound.

Comment: @user264745 I have edited your question. Please try to use Mathjax in your future posts.

Comment: Vitamin d Thank you so much for editing.

Comment: Joe yeah your approach is correct and similar to the reference i provided (sol. to selected ex). I want to know, why my first sol. isn’t working.

Comment: "What if inf(A) is not an element of set A? "  You can similarly prove that if $\inf (A) \not \in A$ that $\sup (-A) \not \in -A$.   And yes the inequality *does* hold becaust:  Since, for all $y > \inf A$ we know $y$ is *not* a lower bound of $A$ (definition of $\inf A$), we should be able to prove that for all $w < -\inf A$ that $w$ is *not* an upper bound of $-A$.

Comment: Yes inequality hold, but I think equality doesn’t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is on the right track, but you don't need to consider separate cases like $x>0$.

Also, notation like $-\sup(-A) \le (x\in A) \ge \inf(A)$ is confusing. I think I know what you are trying to say, but you should not write $a \le b \ge c$.

First, before we go into the details of the proof, lets outline the general steps. Your plan seems to be:

1. Show that $-A$ has a supremum.
2. Show that $-\sup(-A)$ is the infimum of $A$.

That's a good plan. Let's break up step 2 into:

- show that $-\sup(-A)$ is a lower bound for $A$
- show that it is the greatest lower bound of $A$

For step 1, rather than take separate cases, such as $x>0$, just use that we know that $A$ has an infimum (since it is non-empty and bounded below). Then, instead of $x > 0$, we just need $x \ge \inf(A)$. Then we know that $-x \le -\inf(A)$. Hence, $-\inf(A)$ is an upper bound on $-A$. Also, we know that $-A$ is non-empty. Therefore, we know that $-A$ has a supremum. Step 1 complete.

You have step 2a in your proof, but I'll just state it slightly differently:

$\forall x \in A$, we know that $-x \in -A$, so that $-x \le \sup(-A)$, and therefore $x \ge -\sup(-A)$. Hence $-\sup(-A)$ is a lower bound on $A$.

For step 2b, it does ***not*** matter if $\inf(A)$ is in $A$ or not. We just need to show that $-\sup(-A)$ is the greatest lower bound on $A$. We show that by showing that if some number is greater, then it is not a lower bound:

Let $y > -\sup(-A)$. Then $-y < \sup(-A)$, which means that $\exists z \in -A$ such that $-y < z$

(since otherwise $-y$ would be an upper bound of $-A$ that was less than $\sup(-A)$)

Then we know that $-z \in A$ and $-z < y$, so that $y$ is not a lower bound on $A$.

Therefore $-\sup(-A)$ is the greatest lower bound on $A$.

Comment: Great answer! Combination of where I was getting trapped (kind of wrong) and non-ambiguous proof. If I'm not mistaken nature of proof is similar to step 3(last part) of proof of theorem 1.19 (step 2b). Now, I got two different ways to proof this question(both are fundamentally same). Thank you.

Comment: Small correction, last sentence, -sup(-A) is the greatest lower bound.

Comment: You're welcome. That's definitely an important correction!  It was hard bouncing back and forth between typing lower bound and upper bound :)